# how to free the memory of a pointer in C

Tags: c

I wrote a program to concat two strings and make sure the buffer will double the size when there's no enough space.

```
char * strcat_ex(char * * dest, int * n, const char * src){
    int dest_len = 0;
    int src_len = 0;
    if (*dest == NULL)  *n = 0;
    else dest_len = strlen(*dest);
    if (src == NULL)     return *dest;
    else src_len = strlen(src);

    if (dest_len + src_len + 1 > *n) {
        //(1) malloc a new buffer of size 1 + 2 * (strlen(*dest) + strlen(src))
        char * temp;
        temp = (char*) malloc(1 + 2 * (strlen(*dest) + strlen(src)));
        //(2) set '*n' to the size of the new buffer
        *n = 1 + 2 * (strlen(*dest) + strlen(src));
        //(3) copy '*dest' into the beginning of the new buffer
        strcpy(temp, *dest);
        //(4) free the memory '*dest', and then set '*dest' to point to the new buffer
        free(*dest);
        *dest = temp;
    }
    //(5) concatenate 'src' onto the end of '*dest'.
    while (temp) temp++;
    while ((temp++ = src++) =! '\0');
    return *dest;}
```

and this code doesn't work. I got segmentation fault at "free(*dest)".
Please help. Thank you very much!

Here's the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char * * argv){
    printf("\nTesting strcat_ex(...)\n");
    char * str1;
    str1 = "one";
    char * str2;
    str2 = "two";
    int n;
    n = strlen(str1);
    printf("Before strcat_ex, str1 == %p (%s), str2 == %p (%s)\n", str1, str1, str2, str2);
    strcat_ex(&(str1), &n, str2);
    printf("After swap, str1 == %p (%s), str2 == %p (%s)\n", str1, str1, str2, str2);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

Comment: try `free(dest);` instead

Comment: how is dest declared and allocated?

Comment: You need to show how the function is being called.

Comment: And I don't see how this compiles, since `temp` is not in scope at step (5).

Comment: Learn how to use `realloc`. It will save you the `free` by doing it for you if necessary. Aside from that, please show how the function is being called and how the variable passed to the function is declared.

Comment: @user3386109, you are right. I had the char * temp outside of the if before. sorry for the typo

Comment: @user3386109 the function is called in main by     'strcat_ex(&(str1), &n, str2);'

Comment: @bolov, it's defined outside this function in main. and I have uploaded the main.

Comment: @kylek, sorry, it doesn't work. since im passing a pointer of a string (which is a pointer to a set of chars), so it was char**dest in the args and should be *dest to refer to the address of that string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the initial value of `str1` is a pointer to a literal string. That pointer cannot be freed. So the fix is to `malloc` space in `main`, e.g.

```
char *str1 = malloc( 100 );  // allocate an initial buffer
int n = 100;                 // the buffer has 100 bytes
strcpy( str1, "one" );       // put some text in the buffer
```